# Accelerated system + container . Tension to be calculated

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, density, buoyancy

So there is this question which is as follows

> the tension in a string holding a solid block below the surface of a liquid is $T$, as shown. It is given that the density of the solid is more than that of the liquid. Find the tension in the string if the system accelerates upwards with acceleration $a$.

This is the figure provided:

[image]

The answer was 
$T$ $(1 + \frac{a}{g})$

I'm not sure why there is a plus sign there.

My reasoning was that I imagined a real situation where this would happen. Due to the upward acceleration, the block would naturally have a tendency to move towards the base of the container which can be verified by the direction of the pseudo force. So naturally the tension in string should decrease and there should be a minus sign. If the system accelerates upwards at very high values of 'a' , then the tension should be zero, right ?

Comment: Why is the block buoyant if it is denser than the liquid?

Comment: oops my bad. its the other way round. the block is less dense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question drawing a free body is of great help.
In the first case when there was no acceleration of the block upward we come with equation
T+mg=d*v*g

here m is the mass of the body

d is the density of the liquid

v is the volume of the immersed body

In the second case we see that new tension equation would be

T'+ mg+ma(pseudo force will cause acc on the block downwards)= d*v*(g+a)

An important point here is that the buoyant force will also increase as we have to always take the "effective value".
so that just plainly gives the desired eqn T'=T(1+a/g) on solving the two equations.

So, concluding it you were right about the fact that the block tends to move downwards as confirmed by pseudo force but at the same time there was an increase in the buoyant force which can compensate the effect and hence the tension actually increases.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two opposing forces in play here. As we accelerate upwards there is a downwards pseudo force which tries to decrease the tension but the buoyant force also increases due to acceleration and it tries to push the block upwards thus increasing the tension. Both effects are increased in the same proportion that is by the same factor $(1+\frac{a}{g})$, so the net result is that the tension is increased by the same factor (because the laws of motion are linear) and thus you get that result. As this logic says, even for very high values of $'a'$ the tension should not be zero.